# How do I force a method in Groovy to throw an exception

Tags: testing, groovy

I wanted to write a test for a method in Groovy that throws an IOException. The only way for me to simulate this in the test is to force the method to throw this exception 
This is what the original code looks like:

```
    public void cleanUpBermudaFiles(RequestMessage requestMessage)

    {
    final File sourceDirectory = new  File(preferenceService.getPreference("bermuda.landingstrip") + File.separator + requestMessage.getWorkflowId().getValue());

    if(sourceDirectory!=null && sourceDirectory.exists())
    {
         deleteDirectory(sourceDirectory);
    }
    else
    {
        LOG.error("Directory must exist in order to delete");
    }

}

private void deleteDirectory(File directoryToDelete)
{
    try {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(directoryToDelete);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to delete Bermuda files directory located at:" + directoryToDelete.getPath() + "with an exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

MY TEST: (I'm looking for a way to make deleteDirectory throw IOException)

```
     public void testCleanUpBermudaFailure()
    {
    workflowId = new WorkflowId("123456")
    workflowDirectory = new File(srcDirectory, workflowId.value)
    workflowDirectory.mkdir()
    File.createTempFile('foo','.lst', workflowDirectory)
    def exception = {throw new IOException()}

    expect(mockRequestMessage.getWorkflowId()).andReturn(workflowId)
    expect(mockPreferenceService.getPreference("bermuda.landingstrip")).andReturn(srcDirectory.path)
    replay(mockPreferenceService, mockRequestMessage)
    fileCleanUpService.preferenceService = mockPreferenceService
    fileCleanUpService.metaClass.deleteDirectory = exception
    fileCleanUpService.cleanUpBermudaFiles(mockRequestMessage)
    verify(mockPreferenceService, mockRequestMessage)
    assert srcDirectory.listFiles().length == 0, 'CleanUp failed'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service class is a Groovy class, you would want to mock FileUtils like:

```
FileUtils.metaClass.static.deleteDirectory = { File f -> throw new IOException() }
```

However, as ataylor pointed out, you cannot intercept calls if it's a Java class. You can find a nice blog post about it [here](http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2008/04/testing-java-from-groovy-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking a no-arg call to `deleteDirectory`, but the real `deleteDirectory` takes one argument of type `File`.  Try this:

```
def exception = { File directoryToDelete -> throw new IOException() }
...
fileCleanUpService.metaClass.deleteDirectory = exception
```

Comment: Hi taylor. It does not work. The real method is still getting executed causing it to no throw the exception. I am only interested in the exception getting thrown and testing that the exception got thrown .. how do i do that ?

Comment: I have found that if you tweak the closure (say by accepting a parameter as ataylor has here) in a metaClass that running a `grails clean` before running the tests again can help ensure the change is picked up properly.

Comment: Is the service a java object or a groovy object?

Comment: The service is a Java object. Does it make a difference ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does matter.  You can't intercept or mock a call made from a Java object to a Java object with groovy metaClasses.  You may want to look into a Java mocking framework like EasyMock or mockito.